# Fixed: Keras Neural Network on handwritten digits labeling: Model reads the surrounding space instead of digit

Tags: machine-learning, python, numpy

Our assignment consists of labeling handwritten numbers, ranging from 0 to 9.

We build a Convolutional Neural Network that achieves a good accuracy on our labeled testset. We now want to use this model to predict the numbers on our unlabeled dataset, called Z.

When printing out the predictions, it seems that the model predicts the number 0 way too often and that it scores a very low accuracy.

We have:

X_train of float64 and shape(42000, 28, 28, 1)
Y_train of float32 and shape(42000, 10)
X_test of float64 and shape(28000, 28, 28, 1)
Z_test(the unlabeled set) of floats64 and shape(15000, 28, 28, 1)

When printing out the digits I saw that our train and test datasets look like this:

[image]

Our unlabeled dataset, Z, looks like this:

[image]

```
Our code looks like this:

Y_train = train["label"]
X_train = train.drop(labels = ["label"],axis = 1)
X_train = X_train / 255.0
X_test = test / 255.0
X_train = X_train.values.reshape(-1,28,28,1)
X_test = X_test.values.reshape(-1,28,28,1)
Y_train = to_categorical(Y_train, num_classes = 10)
Z_test = unlabeleddata / 255.0
Z_test2 = Z_test.reshape(-1,28,28,1)
```

Is there a solution to fix this problem?

Thanks!

Edit: The problem was fixed with this code:

```
Z_test = unlabeleddata - 255.0
Z_test = unlabeleddata / 255.0
Z_test = Z_test - 1
Z_test = np.absolute(Z_test)
Z_test2 = Z_test.reshape(-1,28,28,1)
```

Comment: I see that writitng the question you already found a solution - that's good (happens more often than one may think).  That said let me ask one thing: are you guys required to solve the handwritten digit classification problem using a deep and/or convolutional netowork?  That is a classical problem that can be solved with very good score with a single layer fully connected network.

Comment: Hi grochmal, we're asked to solve the following assignment:

We have a mnist dataset, a arabic speec dataset with numbers from 0 to 9 and a third dataset which gives True or False when the written and spoken number refer to the same number.

We need to make a model that can predict whether these two datasets refer to the same number.

We're not quite sure how to handle this the best way, and tips are welcome!

Comment: that makes sense, the speech dataset will most likely need a DNN.  keep going.